# take decision from output of external command in perl script

Tags: perl, cmd

I want to take decision based on result of system - external commend's output.
like: In my code I am executing one system command and if that command gives error then I have to do something else something different.
Please help me to achieve this:

```
This is just algorithm ....... i am not able to get value from result  
$result = `dt add $dest_file -c porting`;
if($result = 'error')
{
    do something 1
}
else
{
    do something 2
}
```

please suggest me way to retrieve value in $ result 
I think in this case I should not use system

Comment: What you are doing is wrong change ``=`` to ``==`` or better ``eq`` as it is a string comparison. In addition, since dt probably returns multiple lines, an ``eq`` isn't the right thing use, ``=~`` which means regex

Comment: If I try to print result .... i am not getting anything even if my command dt results in error

Comment: I assume that the above comment wasn't obvious: say `if ($result =~ 'error')` instead.

Comment: what returns if you print `$result`, nothing? empty? what is `dt`? is it your code? a third-party? try to put full-path

Comment: dt is an external command , if i print result it prints nothing not even null

Comment: try to write (in the cmdline), ``whereis dt``, then place in your call the full path to ``dt`` instead of just ``dt``

Answer (score 1):

We have to know what the `dt` command is. I'm assuming it's DITrack which behaves in a nice Unixish way which means it returns a non-zero error code when it fails.

When Perl executes a system command, it returns the exit value (sort of...) in `$?`. If `dt` is DiTrack, it's a standardly implemented such Unix command, and returns a zero exit code when it works, and returns a non-zero exit code when it doesn't work, you can use the `$?` to determine if it succeeded or not:

```
$result = qx(dt add $dest_file -c porting); # qx(...) preferred over back ticks.
if ( $? != 0 ) {
    chomp $result;
    say qq(Everything is okay! Program returned $result);
}
else {
    die qq(Some sort of error has happened);
}
```

The problem is that `$?` returns both the exit code, and *mode of failure*. There's this snippet of code from the [system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) that parses `$?`:

```
if ($? == -1) {
    print "failed to execute: $!\n";
}
elsif ($? & 127) {
    printf "child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
        ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without';
}
else {
    printf "child exited with value %d\n", $? >> 8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using regular expressions:

```
$result = `dt add $dest_file -c porting`;
  if($result =~ /error/)
  {
    do something 1
  }
  else
  {
    do something 2
  }
```

One thing to keep mind is that backticks typically/potentially returns the newline character as well so you need to account for this. Using regex will allow you to get around this quickly.